# SQL Query Peers and above

Tags: sql, sql-server

There are recursive queries available to find all children or parents in a hierarchy (for example in an employee-manager hierarchy) but I couldn't find any example of peers and above/parents

```
EmpID   FName   LName       MgrID
11  Sally   Smith       NULL
1   Alex    Adams       11
2   Barry   Brown       11
3   Lee Osaka       11
4   David   Kennson     11
5   Eric    Bender      11
7   David   Lonning     11
6   Lisa    Kendall     4
8   John    Marshbank   4
12  Barbara ONeill      4
13  Phil    Wilconkinski    4
9   James   Newton      3
10  Terry   OHaire      3
```

So if I want peer-above of EmpID=6 then it should return

```
EmpID   FName   LName       MgrID
11  Sally   Smith       NULL    grandparent/peer
1   Alex    Adams       11  parent-peer
2   Barry   Brown       11  parent-peer
3   Lee Osaka       11  parent-peer
4   David   Kennson     11  (parent of id=6)
5   Eric    Bender      11  parent-peer
7   David   Lonning     11  parent-peer
6   Lisa    Kendall     4   (id=6)
8   John    Marshbank   4   peer
12  Barbara ONeill      4   peer
13  Phil    Wilconkinski    4   peer
```

Any help will be very appreciated

Comment: One way of going about this would be to change the way you're representing your hierarchy. There are other methods of modelling hierarchies in SQL. Perhaps look into SQL Server's `hierarchyid` UDT, adjacency lists, and closure tables.

Comment: Once your usual "find all parents in a hierarchy of X" CTE is run, in the SELECT statement, just join back to the table and grab all of the children of empid (with the exception of the starting empid of "X"). No need to monkey with the recursive portion.

Comment: Why people vote negative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the way your table is currently structured, one way of achieving this is to include a path in your recursive CTE, then parse the path to figure out whether someone belongs to that path in the hierarchy.

For example,

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE 
(
    EmpID INT NOT NULL, 
    FName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    LName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    MgrID INT
);

INSERT @Table (EmpID, FName, LName, MgrID)
VALUES
    (11, 'Sally', 'Smith', NULL),
    (1, 'Alex', 'Adams', 11),
    (2, 'Barry', 'Brown', 11),
    (3, 'Lee', 'Osaka', 11),
    (4, 'David', 'Kennson', 11),
    (5, 'Eric', 'Bender', 11),
    (7, 'David', 'Lonning', 11),
    (6, 'Lisa', 'Kendall', 4),
    (8, 'John', 'Marshbank', 4),
    (12, 'Barbara', 'ONeill', 4),
    (13, 'Phil', 'Wilconkinski', 4),
    (9, 'James', 'Newton', 3),
    (10, 'Terry', 'OHaire', 3);

WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT EmpID, 
           FName, 
           LName, 
           MgrID, 
           Tree = CAST(EmpID AS VARCHAR(255)), 
           Lvl = 1
    FROM @Table
    WHERE MgrID IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT T.EmpID, 
           T.FName, 
           T.LName, 
           T.MgrID, 
           CAST(CTE.Tree + '-' + CAST(T.EmpID AS VARCHAR(255)) AS VARCHAR(255)), -- Your paths will look like '11-4-6'.
           CTE.Lvl + 1
    FROM CTE
    JOIN @Table T ON T.MgrID = CTE.EmpID
)
SELECT EmpID, 
       FName, 
       LName, 
       MgrID,
       Lvl,
       Direct = CASE MIN(CASE WHEN EmpID = Item THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) WHEN 1 THEN 'Direct' ELSE 'Peer' END
FROM CTE
JOIN 
(
    SELECT Item
    FROM CTE
    CROSS APPLY dbo.[DelimitedSplit8K](Tree, '-') D
    WHERE CTE.EmpID = 6
) D ON D.Item = CTE.EmpID 
    OR D.Item = CTE.MgrID
GROUP BY EmpID, FName, LName, MgrID, Lvl;
```

This uses a split function to break up the path and only display people in that path. The split function can be found [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) and looks like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K]
--===== Define I/O parameters
        (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))
--WARNING!!! DO NOT USE MAX DATA-TYPES HERE!  IT WILL KILL PERFORMANCE!
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
 RETURN
--===== "Inline" CTE Driven "Tally Table" produces values from 1 up to 10,000...
     -- enough to cover VARCHAR(8000)
  WITH E1(N) AS (
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
 cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "base" CTE and limits the number of rows right up front
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
                 SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@pString),0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
                ),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t WHERE SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter
                ),
cteLen(N1,L1) AS(--==== Return start and length (for use in substring)
                 SELECT s.N1,
                        ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter,@pString,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000)
                   FROM cteStart s
                )
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.N1),
        Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString, l.N1, l.L1)
   FROM cteLen l
;
```